# C++ functors and templates: error: declaration of 'class List<T>'

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, nested, functor

I've a nested template in side a template class for a method called List::find().
This method gets a functor as input, which is: "Function condition".

```
template<class T>
class List {
....
template<class Function>
Iterator find(Function condition) const;
....
};

template<class T, class Function>
typename List<T>::Iterator List<T>::find(Function condition) const {
   List<int>::Iterator it = this->begin();
   for (; it != this->end(); ++it) {
   if (condition(*it)) {
       break;
   }
   }
   return it;
}
```

The error is:

```
..\list.h:108:62: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class List<T>'
..\list.h:16:7: error: declaration of 'class List<T>'
```

How should I reference List? Why isn't the declaration correct?

### Edit:

Now after changing to:

```
template<class T>
template<class Function>
```

I get these errors:

```
..\list.h:111:30: error: no match for 'operator++' in '++it'
..\list.h:112:18: error: no match for 'operator*' in '*it'
```

which refer to this operator declaration (one of them):

```
template<class T>
typename List<T>::Iterator& List<T>::Iterator::operator++() {
    List<T>::ConstIterator::operator++();
    return *this;
}
```

Why does the declaration of this operator has to be different for each implementation of find()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not

```
template<class T, class Function>
typename List<T>::Iterator List<T>::find(Function condition) const {
   ...
}
```

but rather

```
template<class T>
template<class Function>
typename List<T>::Iterator List<T>::find(Function condition) const {
   ...
}
```

You must "separate" the two `template<...>` (the first for the class, the second for the member function).

Comment: @Eitan Maybe this won't solve your new error, but you are using `List<int>::Iterator` instead of `List<T>::Iterator` inside the function.

Comment: @Eitan: Now that you have a new error, this becomes a new question.  You probably should start up a new question for it.